# What triggers file system check?

Tags: filesystem, startup

What are the conditions that trigger file system check at system startup in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: I think the answer is every 30 boots, unless something went wrong at shutdown previously. I don't see an exact dupe after a quick search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few conditions which will trigger a fsck when a filesystem is mounted.

Firstly the maximum mount count, and the check interval. To see these, try:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

Replace `sda1` with the filesystem you want to check.

You're looking for:

```
Mount count:              9
Maximum mount count:      29
Last checked:             Tue Nov 15 17:15:10 2011
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Sun May 13 18:15:10 2012
```

Here you can see my drive has been mounted 9 times since it was last checked, and it will force a check after 29 mounts just to make sure everything is still okay. It will also do one after 6 months even if the maximum mount count hasn't been reached. (these values are also tweakable with `tune2fs`).

Secondly, if the filesystem is not cleanly unmounted, the next mount attempt will trigger a fsck. This is also in the `tune2fs` output, look for:

```
Filesystem state:         clean
```