# Why does Ubuntu start file checking on every reboot?

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck, disk-check

I have disks with UUID in the below;

```
pc@User:~$ sudo blkid | grep UUID=
/dev/sda2: UUID="1337da3f-187f-4d2a-b3d9-a6997bba783b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3bb046df-4be2-4148-a039-40f3cb987d52"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="1A16-CE88" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="5b5751d9-ee6b-403a-8c42-8f4b9f32b07d"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="NEON" UUID="845C1B3A5C1B2688" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="20a17199-4048-4d52-842a-385cefa14099"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="8ED6B34AD6B33177" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b14046e2-7f02-4db4-8306-fb81704ddabf"
/dev/sda3: UUID="bb99e90a-0e71-4155-a1e2-058ecc84e187" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f7886fce-1da7-4cd0-9251-78e24965ecd7"
/dev/sda4: UUID="b8541bc9-7990-406b-99d6-4cd8435a9fa0" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c9410b9d-f2b9-43ef-9f05-f6313303cce7"
/dev/sda5: UUID="361d0119-cfcd-431c-b797-fb08d5647c5c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3d9b0ee4-2d3e-42b3-bc71-13a80ef497fb"
/dev/sda6: UUID="40945ab1-f123-49ab-a645-c27e40679679" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e5087e8a-7353-40af-a55a-f12ab55faf0d"
/dev/sda7: LABEL_FATBOOT="MEGA" LABEL="MEGA" UUID="2853-C7F3" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="32da27d1-efbd-4d2d-81a3-f79c1e14f2ee"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="db2feaed-2a4c-421e-bf71-d43b5463499c"
```

I disabled file check and `/dev/sda2` which my root disk, but when I trying to reboot my system I get this file check;

```
[***] A start job is running for dev/disk/by-uuid/8c8e15fd-b638-4930-a664-ea326b6f3c23 (1min 5s / 1min 30s)
```

So, how can I disable it?

Note: I did operations in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/103039/1222875) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279617/1222875) answers.

Edit:

```
pc@User:/$ sudo cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1337da3f-187f-4d2a-b3d9-a6997bba783b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=b8541bc9-7990-406b-99d6-4cd8435a9fa0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=1A16-CE88  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=bb99e90a-0e71-4155-a1e2-058ecc84e187 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /tmp was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=40945ab1-f123-49ab-a645-c27e40679679 /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=361d0119-cfcd-431c-b797-fb08d5647c5c /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8c8e15fd-b638-4930-a664-ea326b6f3c23 none            swap    sw              0       0
LABEL=MEGA /mnt/MEGA auto rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=MEGA 0 0
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: I added it to the question. I also made MEGA disk automount in the Disks Edit Mount Options...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears as though your swap partition is missing and your `/etc/fstab` file is still looking for it.

Comment out the line for the swap and reboot the system

```
sudo sed -i 's/UUID=8c8e15fd-b638-4930-a664-ea326b6f3c23/#UUID=8c8e15fd-b638-4930-a664-ea326b6f3c23' /etc/fstab
```

The above line will add a `#` in front of that line so that the system doesn't try to mount a non-existing partition at boot.

Hope this helps!